# Log into Instagram with Java

Tags: java, jsoup, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to log into Instagram programatically but I fail to do so. I need to login to Instagram to first to be able to use their API.
I am using the Jsoup library and here's what I'm doing.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://instagram.com/accounts/login")
                      .data("username", "myUsername")
                      .data("password", "myPassword")
                      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2")
                      .followRedirects(true)
                      .post();
```

This does not work and I am not logged into my instagram account. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you registered your application with Instagram?  You might be interested in their API:  https://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: I haven't looked into this, but, since this is 2015, I'd imagine that Instagram would at least have some protection against plain HTTP request scrapers.

Comment: Yes I have registered my app with Instagram. I still need to log into Instagram from my app to be able to use the API.

Comment: @MikeAnderson check  whether, the application creates session and cookie details

Comment: @vickisys It does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you / anyone never found the solution, there are 3 parameters that IG login requires.

```
username=username&password=password&queryParams={}
```

These all can be found when checking the post data of when you login through the website, application, etc.

Hope this helps you and anyone who couldnt find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it in Java. You can check this repository https://github.com/dokksen/InstagramLoginConsole

The post request looks like this:

```
String response =  webClient.post()
                .uri(login_url)
                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36")
                .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                .header("Referer","https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
                .header("x-csrftoken","all")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
```